# Netty TCP real-time video stream

Tags: java, video-streaming, netty

I'm trying to do a live video stream using Netty TCP.
But I found only HTTP/WEB video streams on Netty, it's all too complicated and I can't figure out what exactly I need to do.

My network has a packet system, and from what I understand, I have to send updated pixels of the previous frame in each packet. I've tried the Xuggler library but I haven't found any guides on how to do a live stream on it via Netty TCP.

I've tried to make code that get the updated pixels out of the image but it uses too much CPU time and takes too long to execute per frame.

My code (image resolution is 1920x1080 and it takes 20ms to execute)

```java
BufferedImage lastFrame, newFrame;
...

long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

int[][] updatedPixels = new int[newFrame.getHeight()][newFrame.getWidth()];
int[] pixels = newFrame.getRGB(0, 0, newFrame.getWidth(), newFrame.getHeight(), null, 0, newFrame.getWidth());
int index = 0, count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < newFrame.getHeight(); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < newFrame.getWidth(); j++) {
    int rgb = pixels[index++];
    if (rgb != lastFrame.getRGB(j, i)) {
      updatedPixels[i][j] = rgb;
      count++;
    }
  }
}

System.out.println("Total pixels changed: " + count + " | Exec time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + "ms");
```

I need to optimize getting updated pixels from image or a library that encodes and decodes images like in my code.

Something like the following (pseudocode):

```java
byte[] changedPixels = VideoLibrary.encode(prevFrame, newFrame);
BufferedImage image = VideoLibrary.decode(prevFrame, changedPixels)
```